# File wont open when method is called from dynamic object array index

Tags: c++, io, dynamic-arrays

The main issue I'm seeing is illustrated in the example below. I don't understand why the readFile method works when the calling object is a static object array index and a singular object initialized on the head, but when I create an array of head objects the call produces a read access error when trying to open the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class B
{
public:
    B() {};
    ~B() {/*proper destructor would go here*/ };
    void readFile(char* file) {
        in.open(file);
        //process file
        in.close();
    };
private:
    ifstream in;
};

class A
{
public:
    A() {};
   ~A() {};
    void create(char* file) {
        B * newB = new B;
        newB->readFile(file); //Works

        B bStaticArray[2];
            for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            bStaticArray[i].readFile(file); //Works
        }

        bDynamicArray = new B *[2]; //pretend this is a dynamic array
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            bDynamicArray[i]->readFile(file); //doesnt work, read access 
            violation when performing open
        }
    }
private:
    B ** bDynamicArray;
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.create("file.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bDynamicArray[i]->readFile(file);` You never initialized `bDynamicArray[i]` to point anywhere, so the pointer value there is undefined. Dereferencing it with `->` invokes undefined behavior. You probably meant for `bDynamicArray` to be a `B*` instead of a `B**`? Side note: use vectors instead of managing your own memory. There is no reason to be fiddling with dynamic array allocation by hand.

Comment: thanks for the comments @cdhowie. my double pointer was the problem, i just wasnt seeing it and needed another set of eyes. thanks for the comment on vectors, I know that they should be used, but i am just messing around and wanted to take the time to try and learn some more about raw dynamic memory allocation

Comment: Please use http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @KhouriGiordano Why? This question would be completely off-topic and downvoted on Code Review. Please read [_A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777) and refrain from making inappropriate referrals.

Comment: @200_success thanks for this comment, after reading the link you included, I do agree that this is the incorrect place to post, but I am happy KhouriGiordano posted this, because I did not know it existed.